# How to set background image for button in Android?

Tags: android, button, background, drawable

I Imported one image inside the drawable-mdpi, then implemented the image from button, but an error occurs `no resource found here`. How do I fix this issue?

I tried this:

main.xml

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable-mdpi/button_focused_orange"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Since you are new here, you may accept an answer by clicking the small 'Tick' arrow. This will increase your accept ration and even help others who face similar issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All drawables are compiled under a single resource name, i.e. `drawable`. Android automatically chooses from which folder to take the drawable depending on the screen size, and hence you do not need to specifically point it out. Also, hard coding Android to use resources from a particular folder kind of defeats the purpose of having multiple folders for Android to choose from. To solve this issue, simply change:

```
    android:background="@drawable-mdbi/button_focused_orange"/>
```

To

```
    android:background="@drawable/button_focused_orange"/>
```

Comment: Error comes in Source file, R cannot be resolved to a variable. how to fix this error? please help me

Comment: Now is a good time to go to Project -> Clean. Also, make sure there is no import android.R; type of line in your Java files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Now i clean the project and remove android.R, then i run the app, same error comes again

Comment: You cannot get a build error at runtime. It is impossible. Check the LogCat to see which error you are getting.

Comment: when i import the image inside the drawable folder, that error comes

Comment: Can u please tell, i have add a image the error comes so any format file need it

Comment: Yes i remove, now i used this android:background="@drawable/New_Button_One"

Comment: You cannot have capital letters in the name. Change the image name to new_button_one.

Comment: Wow! its working, thank you so much Raghav. can you please help future also.

Answer (score 4):

Should be `@drawable/button_focused_orange`

Not `@drawable-mdpi/button_focused_orange`

Comment: i have one doubt, can u please help

Comment: Error comes in Source file, R cannot be resolved to a variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project. 
If you are usuing Eclipse you can do this by clicking *project* -> *clean* and then *project* -> *Build project*

Comment: There is a problem in his XML. Cleaning the project without solving the problem will not change anything.

Comment: And still... sometimes cleaning fixes a caching build in the Android build process. It's really something to do when you're stumped.

Comment: @RaghavSood You are right, I didn't catch that one. I left my answer up because of what _bitbox_ said

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mention -mdpi to add background images, simply use drawable only. Here is you revised code. Try this.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_focused_orange"/>
```